# Flutter web : Get with JSON body , doesnt work

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am unable to get this code working with Flutter web (it works in android+ios)

```
http.Request req = http.Request('GET', uri)
    ..body = json.encode(md)
    ..headers.addAll({
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer ${token}",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    });
```

I checked fiddler output , body is missing . Any suggestions to get it working

Comment: You may need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin at server side, not at this flutter code.

Comment: What's the content of the md?